# How to prevent indexing field?

Tags: asp.net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to prevent indexing Id field for search using Nest attributes.

```
[Number(type: NumberType.Long, IncludeInAll = false, Index = false)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work with the approach that you're taking?

Comment: Earlier I was trying 
await _elasticClient.IndexAsync(searchModel); 

Now, I am first creating the mapping
await _elasticClient
                .MapAsync<TEntitySearchModel>(m => m.AutoMap());

It is working now.

Comment: good to hear. Feel free to close this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mapping first.

```
_elasticClient .MapAsync<TEntitySearchModel>(m => m.AutoMap());
```